Axiomatic derivation of formula $[A \implies (B \implies C)] \implies [(A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C)]$
I was going through "An Introduction to Proof Theory" by Manscou, Galvan and Zach and I was trying to do every exercise. Unfortunately, I got stuck at the problem 2.25 E3 and there are no hints at the book. I've tried to start with axiom G4 and G8 as well as I have tried to work backwards from the consequent by guessing what axiom could be used last. I also looked how in the book the same formula was proven in different axiomatic system, but the axioms are very different so it got me nowhere. Therefore I will be very grateful for hints or solution to the following question.
Given axioms:
G1. $A \implies A$
G2. $A \implies (B \implies A)$
G3. $(A \implies (A \implies B)) \implies (A \implies B)$
G4. $(A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies (B \implies (A \implies C))$
G5. $(A \implies B) \implies ((B \implies C) \implies (A \implies C))$
G6. $(A \land B) \implies A$
G7. $(A \land B) \implies B$
G8. $(A \implies B) \implies ((A \implies C) \implies (A \implies (B \land C)))$
G9. $A \implies (A \lor B)$
G10. $B \implies (A \lor B)$
G11. $(A \implies C) \implies ((B \implies C) \implies ((A \lor B) \implies C))$
G12. $(A \implies B) \implies ((A \implies \neg B) \implies \neg A)$
G13. $\neg A \implies (A \implies B)$
And one inference rule:
$$
\frac{A \qquad A \implies B}{B} MP
$$
Prove (without deduction theorem): $[A \implies (B \implies C)] \implies [(A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C)]$
For context E1 was to prove that given that you have $A$ and $B$ you could conclude $A \land B$ and E2 was to prove that given that you have $A \implies B$ and $B \implies C$ you could conclude $A \implies C$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hint. Separately consider two cases: A is true and A is false. In each case, look for an axiom to use.

@RosieF I think that the proof ought to be done without using valuing over truth and false. It wasn't even defined by this point.

Fair enough. I rephrase my two cases: $A$ and ¬$A$.

Got you, I'll try this later today, thanks

Look at Tarski-Bernays axiom system in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus

I wonder if you can skip this weird axiom system and go straight into some form of natural deduction that is more widely used. The above result could then be obtained using only the rules of introduction and elimination of '=>'.

@RosieF Note that this system is for Intuitionistic Logic, so trying to do a proof by cases with $A$ and $\neg A$ won’t work.

@DanChristensen I know, it can be easily done in a natural deduction system, but this is not the problem.

Apologies if this is off topic, but I have not studied proof theory so I may well be missing something important here. I can see that you want to use the axioms given. What advantages if any do they have over natural deduction in the study of proof theory?

Generally, you sometimes want to use axiomatic system, because they are easier to reason about metatheoretically. Still though in metatheory it's much easier to use natural deduction or sequent calculus. I think that in this case it's just for pure training and to show that you can do this in this system and to later see why other systems are easier to use.

Incidentally, I think in a linear logic variant where you can "discard" hypotheses but not "duplicate" hypotheses, all axioms except G3, G8, and G12 hold, and also in that logic the statement you want to prove is not derivable.  So, if that's correct, any proof is going to have to use at least one of G3, G8, or G12; and since you're working with a statement in the implicational fragment, G3 seems the most likely one.

@DanielSchepler Well my proof used G3, so it is at least anecdotal confirmation haha

Incidentally, I was able to use some "combinator abstraction" and "Curry-Howard correspondence" sort of stuff to come up with a proof in 11 steps using only G3, G4, G5, and MP.  I guess that beats your solution in a sense since each E2 expands to 3 steps.  Let me know if you'd like to see it written out.  (For my future reference: The schema for the proof is summarized in the combinator identity $S \equiv D(D\Delta)(DDC)$ where $S$ corresponds to the statement you want to prove, $D$ corresponds to G5, $C$ corresponds to G4, and $\Delta$ corresponds to G3.)

Oh wait, my $D$ combinator corresponded to an axiom $(B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ which reverses the hypotheses from G5 as stated.  So, I'd have to rework the abstractions to take that into account with the reversed $D'$ combinator.

So after those adjustments, it's 15 steps, same length as yours if both instances of E2 are expanded.

@DanielSchepler oh thank you, I'll try to get it by your method on my own. I'll have to read some about things you mentioned, because I don't know them (if you have some good resources I'll be thankful for recommendation). And I definitely will reach you out either to ask you for proof written out if I'll fail or I'll let you know, that I managed to get your result.

I don't know of many good in-depth references; you could probably start with the Wikipedia pages on the Curry-Howard correspondence and on combinator calculus, though I don't know how helpful they would be since they don't mention my use case for them.

I was able to finally solve it. I checked link from Bram28 and then looked some more into axiomatizations for propositional calculus. In the end I was able to find sufficiently similar system of axioms in "Elementarne wprowadzenie w logikę formalną" by Porębska and Suchoń, which is introductory formal logic textbook for students of humanities from 1991.
\begin{align*}
&1. (A \implies B) \implies [(B \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A  \implies (A \implies C))] \\ &| G5 \qquad C/(A \implies C) \\
&2. [(A \implies B) \implies ((B \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A  \implies (A \implies C)))] \implies \\
&[(B \implies (A \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A  \implies (A \implies C)))] \\
&|G4 \qquad A/(A \implies B), B/(B \implies (A \implies C)), C/(A \implies C)\\
&3. (B \implies (A \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A  \implies (A \implies C))) \\
&|MP \quad 1,2\\
&4. (A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies (B \implies (A \implies C)) \\
&|G4 \\
&5. (A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A  \implies (A \implies C))) \\
&|E2 \quad 3,4 \\
&6. [(A \implies B) \implies (A \implies (A \implies C))] \implies \\ 
&[((A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))] \\
&|G5 \qquad A/(A \implies B), B/(A \implies (A \implies C)), C/(A \implies C) \\
&7. (A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies \\ 
&[((A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))] \\
&|E2 \quad 6,7 \\
&8. [(A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies \\ 
&(((A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C)))] \implies \\
&[((A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C)) \implies \\
&((A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C)))] \\
&|G4 \qquad A/(A \implies (B \implies C)), B/((A \implies (A \implies C)), \\
&C/((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C)) \\
&9.((A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C)) \implies \\
&((A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))) \\
&|MP \quad 8,9 \\
&10.(A \implies (A \implies C)) \implies (A \implies C) \\
&|G3 \qquad B/C \\
&11. ((A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))) \\
&|MP \quad 9,10 \qquad \blacksquare
\end{align*}
